# как работает функция copy

Tags: javascript

```js
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
  isAdmin: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: true
};

function copy() {
  // объявляем переменную dst и присваиваем нулевой объект из arguments
  var dst = arguments[0];
  // начиная с первого объекта перечисляем в цикле  
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     // объявляем переменную arg и присваиваем объект из arguments
    var arg = arguments[i];
    // в цикле перебиваем свойства объектов 
    for (var key in arg) {
      // тут я не могу понять dst[key] = arg[key]; по идеи в переменную dst[key] присваивается свойства  arg[key] 
      // только arg[key] обозначает значение свойства, т.е. если переменная обозначеает arg ==
      // user получим false и т. д. а как же тогда ключи т.е. isAdmin и т.д. ?
      dst[key] = arg[key];
    }
  }

  return dst;
}

console.log(copy(vasya, user))
```

```js
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};


for(var key in vasya){
  console.log(key + ' ' + vasya[key])
};
```

Comment: Может создаваемые переменные запутывают... По сути, это `vasya[isAdmin] = user[isAdmin]; vasya[isEmailConfirmed] = user[isEmailConfirmed];` — у первого объекта создаются новые ключи, с такими же названиями, что и у второго... и присваиваются им такие же значения, что и у второго.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME понятно спасибо, Вы вернулись ... плохо бросать маленьких ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
  isAdmin: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: true
};

function copy() {
  // объявляем переменную dst и присваиваем нулевой объект из arguments
  var dst = arguments[0];
  // начиная с первого объекта перечисляем в цикле  
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    // объявляем переменную arg и присваиваем объект из arguments
    var arg = arguments[i];
    // В цикле из объекта 'arg' "копируем" свойства и их значения в объект 'dst'
    for (var key in arg) {
    /* 
    Если в объекте 'dst' нету свойста 'key' это свойство присваивается объекту 
    'dst', после чего свойству 'key' в объекте 'dst' присваивается значение 
    свойства 'key' объекта 'arg' 
    */
    // Вот как это выглядит на первой итерации: vasya['isAdmin'] = user['isAdmin'];
    dst[key] = arg[key];
    /* После первой итерации объект 'vasya' будет равен vasya = {
                                                          age: 21,
                                                          name: 'Вася',
                                                          surname: 'Петров',
                                                          isAdmin: false,
                                                        } 
    */
    }
  }

  return dst;
}

console.log(copy(vasya, user))
```

Кстати в нашем случае можно и без цикла:

```
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
```

Идентичный код без цикла:

```
var vasya = {
    age: 21,
    name: 'Вася',
    surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
    isAdmin: false,
    isEmailConfirmed: true
};

function copy() {
  var dst = arguments[0];
  var arg = arguments[1];

  for (var key in arg) {     
    dst[key] = arg[key];   
  }

  return dst;
}

console.log(copy(vasya, user))
```

Comment: _Кстати в нашем случае можно и без цикла:_ - нет не можем, потому что `copy` описана для более общего случая, когда в один объект могут копироваться свойства сразу с нескольких других.

Comment: @Problemon понятно спасибо